# How to call a function right after another function has executed without button onpress

Tags: react-native

I have two functions and I am trying to call GetReceipt when the button (with uploadphoto function) has been clicked and right after the UploadPhoto function like getting data right after uploading a photo.

I tried putting `this.GetReceipt()` inside the `UploadPhoto()` function somehow it does not work but if i separate them into two different buttons both functions work perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
UploadPhoto=(pickedImagePath)=> {
        
        var pickedImagePath = this.state.pickedImagePath;
        console.log(pickedImagePath);
        var APIURL="http://10.0.2.2/api/postform.php";
        let uriParts = pickedImagePath.split('/');
        let image = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
        var ImageData= new FormData();
        ImageData.append('photo', {
            uri:pickedImagePath,
            name: image,
            type: 'image/jpeg'
        })
        
        fetch(APIURL,
            {
                headers:{
                    'Accept':'application/json',
                    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
                },
                method:'POST',
                
                body: ImageData
            })
        .then((response)=>
        {
            console.log('succ ')
            console.log(response)
            
        })   
        .catch((error)=>
        {
            console.log('err ')
            console.log(error)
        }
        )
       
    }
    GetReceipt=()=> {
        var title = this.state.title;
        var amount = this.state.amount;
        var transactionType = this.state.transactionType;
        var note = this.state.note;
        var date = this.state.date;

        var APIURL="http://10.0.2.2/api/getform.php";

        var headers2={
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application.json'
        }

    

        fetch(APIURL,
            {
                method:'POST',
                headers: headers2,
               
            })
        .then((response)=>response.text()) 
        .then((response)=>
        {
            // this.setState({array:response});
            this.setState({title:response[3]});
            this.setState({amount:response[0]});
            this.setState({date:response[1]});
            this.setState({note:response[2]});
            // this.setState({results:response});
           console.log("results:",response[2]);
           console.log("merchant:",this.state.title);
           console.log("results:",response);
        })   
        .catch((error)=>
        {
            alert("Error"+error);
        }
        ) 
       
       
    }
```

Comment: have you called GetReceipt() in then() of UploadPhoto?

Comment: ahh thanks man i'm such an idiot i actually tried putting it but i wrote it without the () now it works thank you @ZaidQureshi